# Can I avoid password typing using okinit utility?

Tags: windows, oracle, kerberos

In my configuration i have:

- Domain controller (Windows Server 2008 R2)
- Oracle database server (Windows Server 2016 Standard)
- Client (Windows 10 Pro)

example.ru - is domain name.

mydb - is sid of database.

I use Kerberos authentification.

At DB server I made user:

```
CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY as 'myuser@EXAMPLE.RU';
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO myuser;
```

At client I login as domain user **myuser**.

Obtain ticket for myuser:

```
okinit myuser
```

Then, okinit **asking password**, i type it

Then i login in database:

```
sqlplus /@mydb
```

Connection is successful.

But after 8 hours, if i want login in database again, i must do "okinit myuser" again and type the password.

**Can I avoid password typing?** Will it be secure?
Maybe I must configure **ticket_lifetime** and **renew_lifetime** in krb5.conf (and renew ticket without password)?

Comment: What options does the `okinit` program have? I assume it comes with Oracle DB? (I'm wondering if it's just a 1:1 clone of MIT Kerberos `kinit` or if it's different.) And, are you using a domain account on your Win10 workstation or a local account?

Comment: @user1686 okinit is utility of Oracle Advanced Security. I am using a domain account

Comment: @user1686 is Oracle's clone of MIT kerberos kinit. That's the root of the problem, Oracle ships their database with their own kerberos libraries/tools/configs which do not integrate at all with Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can not do much about that. Oracle's Kerberos implementation is VERY old and until now it did not advance to today's standards.

Windows/AD ecosystem is combination of two technologies LDAP+Kerberos. AD has own Kerberos server, Windows login service is a Kerberos client. And here comes the problem. Nowadays Window won't let you see your own Kerberos TGT(ticket granting ticket). If you execute `klist tgt` you will see all zeros.

In order to use Kerberos SSO, your SW have to integrate with with Microsoft proprietary API called SSPI. In order to integrate Oracle thick client library with SSPI you have to place this into our sqlnet.ora

`SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME=MSLSA:`

or

`SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME=OSMSFT:`

This instructs Oracle's client library to withdraw Kerberos tickets from Windows native cache rather that from a file.
I'm not sure if this will work for you. It is not well documented. Use this option for googling. Generally integrating Oracle with Kerberos is a rabbit hole.

In case of Java/JDBC it is even more problematic. It took 7+ years to add support for SSPI into Java JDK. Then support was added into JDBC drivers.
See example bellow.
But support in Oracle SQL Developer is still pending. Enhancement request was created years ago and still no progress.

```
/*
  Copyright (c) 2021, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

  This software is dual-licensed to you under the Universal Permissive License
  (UPL) 1.0 as shown at https://oss.oracle.com/licenses/upl or Apache License
  2.0 as shown at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. You may choose
  either license.

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
*/

/*
   DESCRIPTION
    This sample shows how to use SSO uging Kerberos in Windows.
    Since WIN2019 allowtgtsessionkey registry key is not available 
    and the only option how to acces Kerberos TGT is via Java's SSPI bridge.
    
   PREREQUISITIES
    - Confirure Kerberos authentication for Oracle database as describe here:
      https://blog.pythian.com/part-4-implementing-oracle-database-single-sign-on-using-kerberos-active-directory-and-oracle-cmu/
      
   - Create DB user identified extenally as:
     CREATE USER <AD LOGIN> IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY AS '<AD LOGIN>@<AD REALM>';
     GRANT CONNECT TO <AD LOGIN>;
     
   - Check your Windows has generater Kerb tickets during logon
     klist tgt
     klist
     
   - Connect to database using this program. 
     Java's SSPI bridge should be used to renerate required Kerberos ticket for SSO.
   
*/
     
package kerb;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.ietf.jgss.GSSCredential;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager;
import org.ietf.jgss.GSSName;
import org.ietf.jgss.Oid;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionBuilder;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import oracle.net.ano.AnoServices;

// The whole code was inspired by
// https://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/105-Oracle-Driver-and-Kerberos.html

public class GSSAuthSSPIConnectSample {
    // This should return your AD LOGIN
    String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
    // This should return your AD KERBEROS REALM
    String domain = System.getenv("USERDNSDOMAIN");
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dbhost1:1521/DBSERVICE";

    public GSSAuthSSPIConnectSample() {
    }

    public void doit() throws Exception
    {
        // Use env variable SSPI_BRIDGE_TRACE=1 in order to trace Javas sspi_bridge.dll plugin
        // export SSPI_BRIDGE_TRACE=1
        
        // Various useful tracing options
        //System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", "D:/devel/UCP/target/classes/OracleLog.properties");      
        //System.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.Trace", "true");      

        //System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        //System.setProperty("sun.security.spnego.debug", "true");
        //System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.debug", "true");
        //System.setProperty("java.security.debug", "true");
        //System.setProperty("sun.security.nativegss.debug", "true");

        System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.native", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.jgss.lib", "sspi_bridge.dll");

        Oid krb5Oid = new Oid("1.2.840.113554.1.2.2");
        GSSManager manager = GSSManager.getInstance();

        GSSName srcName = manager.createName(username + "@" + domain, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME);
        GSSCredential cred = manager.createCredential(srcName
                , GSSCredential.DEFAULT_LIFETIME
                , krb5Oid, GSSCredential.INITIATE_ONLY);

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(AnoServices.AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY_SERVICES, "(" + AnoServices.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5 + ")");
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES,"( " + AnoServices.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5 + " )");
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_AUTHENTICATION_KRB5_MUTUAL, "true");

        OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL(url);
        ods.setConnectionProperties(prop);
        OracleConnectionBuilder builder = ods.createConnectionBuilder();
        OracleConnection conn = builder.gssCredential(cred).build();
        
        String auth = ((OracleConnection)conn).getAuthenticationAdaptorName();
        System.out.println("Authentication adaptor:"+auth);

        String sql = "select user from dual";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println("whoami: " + rs.getString(1));

        conn.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GSSAuthSSPIConnectSample test = new GSSAuthSSPIConnectSample();
        try {
            test.doit();
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But after 8 hours, if i want login in database again, i must do "okinit myuser" again and type the password.
>
> Can I avoid password typing? Will it be secure? Maybe I must configure ticket_lifetime and renew_lifetime in krb5.conf (and renew ticket without password)?

In theory yes, depending on how your realm is configured, setting renew_lifetime to `14d` (the typical maximum) – or doing `okinit -r 14d` – would let you use `okinit -R` to extend the lifetime to 8h again and again, for up to two weeks.

Note that you must keep renewing the tickets *before* they expire.

Ideally Oracle should use the Windows LSA ticket cache, which MIT Kerberos can use through the `MSLSA:` cache type (as in ibre5041's answer)... but I don't think it works properly these days. The way "MSLSA:" works is not by letting LSA/SSPI handle everything, but by extracting the raw TGT out of the LSA cache and letting MIT Kerberos do the rest, and the ability to extract the TGT is not only [disabled by default](https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/ec71ac1cabbb3926f8ffaf71e1ad007e4e56e0e5/src/windows/README#L246-L268) but also outright incompatible with Credential Guard. So, continuing to `okinit` separately will be the less-bad choice.

Comment: Note: This registry key AllowTgtSessionKey was introduced on Windows server 2000. It does not work anymore: "With active Credential Guard in Windows 10 and later versions of Windows, you can't enable sharing the TGT session keys with applications anymore."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-protocol-registry-kdc-configuration-keys

Oracle official documentation still recommends it. Also many HOWTOS still recommend. The truth is, it does not work anymore.

Comment: Is okinit -R is supported in Windows? When i do "okinit -R" at client I have
"Options not supported or syntax error." And when I do "okinit /?"  i have "Usage:okinit [-f] [-l lifetime] [-c cache] [username] [-e enctype]*"

Comment: Sounds like it's not as much of a "clone of MIT Kerberos kinit" then, sadly... It should not be an OS-dependent option – I suppose Oracle just omitted the option in general for some reason. My next choice would be to download actual "MIT Kerberos for Windows" (or perhaps look for the Java kinit.exe that it often installs) and try that, as the credential cache file formats are likely to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 23c JDBC Thin driver, you could configure the kerberos credentials using username and password properties. The driver would internally create the kerberos context using the supplied credentials.

Example code : https://gist.github.com/Kuassim/3a628317a4501a0004b5e21fde829696

Documentation :
https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/database/whats-in-oracledb23c-for-java-developers.pdf