Is there a way to use a system variable in the sqlnet.ora file?
I have the Oracle 21c client installed on Windows 11 desktop. I have setup Oracle's OS Authentication which requires a kerberos ticket to exist on the user's desktop. I would like the ticket location parameter SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME to be the system parameter, USERPROFILE. The entry in sqlnet.ora would be SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME="%USERPROFILE%\krb5client.cc" however it is not working. It not using the variable to find the file. How can I set this parameter so the sqlnet.ora file can be leveraged by all users?
I tried adding an ifile parameter in the sqlnet.ora then set the value. It's not recognizing the %USERPROFILE% variable. I'm getting an error file not found.

If there isn't an easier way, you could always write a batch or powershell script that overwrites or rebuilds the file programmatically any way you need. Execute on logon or schedule, whatever is needed.

Do you really need it? You can use Windows SSPI API to retrieve Kerberos tickets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77726836/836215 You not need to store kerberos ticket in a cache.

@ibre5041- I started with using the In-Memory ticket option however Oracle support recommended not. So, I'm stuck with putting a kerberos ticket on the users desktop and looking for an easy way to deploy one sqlnet.ora file instead of updating each one per user.
