Is it possible to store a ticket cache for Kerberos not in file?
In my configuration i have:

Domain controller
Oracle database server (Windows Server 2016 Standard)
Client (Windows 10 Pro)

Kerberos authentication is configured. The ticket cache is stored in a file (system variable KRB5CCNAME is set on client).
The question is: is it possible to store a ticket cache not in file?
I founded information about the OSMSFT/ MSLSA option (storing a ticket cache in Windows memory). But as I understand it, it isn’t possible with active Credential Guard in Windows 10 and later versions of Windows.
Are there other ways to store ticket cache? If not, please share links to Windows/Oracle documentation that can prove this (proof links is needed for discussion with the customer).

Do you use Java or sqlplus?

Does the Oracle software mention SSPI support anywhere? If it were able to use that, then it could rely on Windows' existing Kerberos implementation (including LSA ticket storage and Credential Guard and all)... proof of absence might be difficult though.

@user1686 They mention and it works. See source code example in previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77726836/836215

@ibre5041 sqlplus

Unfortunately OSMSFT/ MSLSA options are not well documented. It is not only about storing ticket in memory, but ather using LSA api to get it. Since Credential Guard is in place, you can not use LSA api anymory, but you have to use SSPI. It seem that sqlplus/oci.dll supports SSPI too,
